# Androidの物理キーボードとソフトウエアキーボードの切替

Tags: android

Androidでプログラム上で物理キーボードのON/OFFをすることは出来るのでしょうか？

ソフトウエアキーボードのON/OFFはInputMethodManagerで可能なのですが、物理キーボードとソフトウエアキーボードの切替が可能なAPIがわかりませんでした。無いのかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

Android には物理キーボードとソフトウェアキーボードの切り替えが出来る API は存在しませんので、プログラム上から ON/OFF で切り替えるということができません。

他人任せな回答で申し訳ありませんが、同様の質問と思われる本家 StackOverFlow の質問を載せておきます。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244816/switch-from-physical-to-software-keyboard